# How can I restart AnimationControler from new duration in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have AnimationControllr start with x hours and it conunt down until it become 0 I need to restart this controller from y hours when its status is completed in initstate();
How can I do that??

this is my code :

```
void initState() {
setState(() {
  super.initState();
  controller = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration:Duration(
      hours: calculatHourDuration(), minutes: calculatMinDuration(),
  ))..addStatusListener((state) =>
  {
    if(state == AnimationStatus.completed)
      setState((){

controller.reset();
controller.duration=new Duration(
  hours: calculatHourDuration(), minutes: calculatMinDuration(),) ;
           controller.reverse(
               from:controller.value == 0.0 ? 1.0: controller.value);
      }
      )});

  controller.reverse(
      from:controller.value == 0.0 ? 1.0: controller.value);
});

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by edit the value of controller when its status is dismissed like this :
void initState() {

```
setState(() {
  if(itsTime)

  super.initState();
  controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(
        hours: calculatHourDuration(),
        minutes: calculatMinDuration(),
      ))
    ..addStatusListener((state) => {
          if (state == AnimationStatus.dismissed)
            setState(() {
              controller.value = 1.0;
              isFas = !isFas;
              controller.duration = Duration(
                hours: calculatHourDuration(),
                minutes: calculatMinDuration(),
              );
              print(controller.duration);
              print(controller.value);
              controller.reverse(
                  from: controller.value == 0.0 ? 1.0 : controller.value);
            })
        });

  controller.reverse(
      from: controller.value == 0.0 ? 1.0 : controller.value);
});
```

}